# URLSession Response wired issue

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am refactor an API request in my app, the old version is written by old framework `ASI http request`.

The api is a `GET` request but keep getting data with some script string response, which is never call completion block.

I am trying to use `URLSession to replace` the old `ASI` framework. And keep getting the response in `URLSessionDataDelegate` method.

Here is my `URLSession code`:

```
func connect(server: String, delegate: URLSessionDataDelegate) {

    guard let url = URL(string: server) else {
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.qualityOfService = .background
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: delegate, delegateQueue: queue)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request)
    task.resume()
}
```

Then

```
class PushServerManager {

   //Call connect here 
   func xxx() {
       connect(server: xxx, delegate: self)
   }
}

extension PushServerManager: URLSessionDataDelegate {
    
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data) {

    guard let response = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
        return
    }

    print(response)

}
```

The `response` are some script tags like:

```
<script> xxxx </script>
<script> xxxx </script>
<script> xxxx </script>
<script> xxxx </script>
<script> xxxx </script>
```

Then I parse the response by:

```
func parseScriptTag(content: String) -> [String] {
        
        guard let expression = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<script>(.*?)</script>") else {
            return []
        }
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: content.count)
        let matches = expression.matches(in: content, options: [], range: range)
        let results = matches.enumerated().map { match -> String? in
            if let matchRange = Range(match.element.range, in: content) {
                return String(content[matchRange])
            } else {
                return .none
            }
        }

        let aaa = results.compactMap { $0 }
        return aaa
    }
```

Everything looks work perfect, but there's a response with many `<script> xxx </script>` lines. The with my `parseScriptTag` I alway missed the last 3 or 4 lines with a very important status information. I checked the script response very carefully seems the last 3 or 4 lines nothing special. Like below, from 97 to 100 are missed.

```
<script> 1xxxx </script>
<script> 2xxxx </script>
<script> 3xxxx </script>
<script> 4xxxx </script>
<script> 5xxxx </script>
...
<script> 97xxxx </script>
<script> 98xxxx </script>
<script> 99xxxx </script>
<script> 100xxxx </script>
```

Back the the old version ASI http request, what I realized is in the ASI receive data method:

```
 - (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {


}
```

The data response twice once with the line from 1 to 96 and the second is from 97 to 100.

Then I wondering if the `response` of `URLSession` in my usage are overwritten somehow? That is when two responses are coming very quickly one after another then `Data` changed?

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: ``let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: content.count) should be `let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: content.utf16.count)` because it's on "NSRange", and "Objective-C length calculation which is UTF16 and could create issue. In the `urlSession(_:dataTask:didReceive:)`, do you append the data until you get the `urlSession(_:task:didCompleteWithError:)`? It's unclear if you get all the data or not, meaning you don't get the 97-100 because you didn't parsed it correctly or not. Also, the `guard let` fails in your case?

Comment: It could be that the `data` passed to the delegate doesn't always end with a clean `<script>...</script>` tag pair and the regex is failing. As @Larme asked do you accumulate all the data before processing it or do you try and process it as it is received?  Would it not be simpler to just pass a closure to receive the data rather than using the delegate method? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask

Comment: @Larme thanks, I will use `utf16` and try. What interesting is today the response contains less data it works. But when there are more data,  I think it would happened. As this is the  legacy stuff, the design is never complete which is like socket and keep getting data. So no need to append final data.I think there could be the parsed data not correctly issue. I will update anything valuable if I come across this issue again. Thanks!

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah, as I explained above this is a bit legacy, the request never call complete.